# SonicWALL HA w/ Dual WAN HSRP from two redundant switches

Tags: redundancy, wan, sonicwall, hsrp

We're adding two SonicWALL NSA 2600 firewalls to our current setup. We currently get two WAN connections from two separate Cisco routers running on the same external subnet with what I believe is HSRP. Right now we run these two connections into two Cisco switches, and all of our computers then plug into both switches with NIC teaming.

In the new setup, we'd like to create a 3-port VLAN on each switch, one port for the WAN connection from the Internet and two ports for each NSA 2600. I've got the WAN port setup from one switch to each SonicWALL in HA mode. If I add the second switch connections to X2, I can't figure out how get the bridged in the Network section. If I choose the WAN zone, I just get Static, Wire Mode, and Tap Mode. Static doesn't make much sense, since I'd need to pick a new IP address. Wire Mode will only let me choose unused interfaces (X4 and X5), and Tap Mode looks totally useless.

Does anyone have any tips on how to make this work or where to learn more about getting something like this working (and maintains full redundancy)?

In case a diagram might help someone understand what I'm trying to do:

[image: Network Setup Diagram]

Here is what it looked like pre-firewall:

[image: Old Network Setup Diagram]

Here are pictures of what I'm seeing on my LAN side:

[image: LAN bridge]

Nothing like that seems to exist on the WAN side:

[image]

Comment: Jake, thank you for your question; however, you [already got an answer on SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/583771/sonicwall-ha-w-dual-wan-hsrp-from-two-redundant-switches).  Could you add explicit information in your question about what is lacking so far in that solution?

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer that maintains redundancy. The only solution I received there involved adding a single point of failure load balancer, and a colleague commended that this stack might be more appropriate for this networking question.

Comment: Do you have the High Availability Upgrade license for your NSA firewalls?

Comment: @Ron Yes we do, it's setup and works great. Our main problem is getting the redundant WAN connections into both firewalls while maintaining full redundancy.

Comment: As stated on SF, the only way you will get around the limitations of Sonicwall is adding a loadbalancer or similar intermediary device.  This is a limitation of the Sonicwall firmware.  As also suggested you could open a case with Sonicwall.  The original question could have been updated to include maintaining redundancy instead of being redundant by asking the question again...

Comment: @MikeNaylor, I appreciate your help, and that may be the case. I added it here, because I thought it was more on topic at this site given it's dedicated solely to networks, and thus someone might have more information or another suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to connect both switches together and create two vlans that span across both switches.  Connect the routers and the WAN side of the FW to VLAN 1.  Connect the LAN side and the servers to VLAN 2.  If you run HSRP on the routers, that is your default gatewway for the firewall.  Here is a logical diagram.  Let me know if you need help configuring trunking on the switches.

[image: HA Logical diagram]

Comment: HA for Sonicwalls in this setup would not work for a link failing.  There is Failover and Load Balancing on each Sonicwall device that detects down links on each firewall.  The HA Pair protects against a Sonicwall Device not being available.  It synchronizes settings and checks to see if the other device is up.  If the other Sonicwall goes down, the HA Sonicwall picks up the slack.  In your diagram if Link 1 fails on the Master Sonicwall, the link for all of the devices on vLAN 2 would still go down as the Secondary Sonicwall will not pick up the workload.

Comment: Which link are you talking about?

Comment: From vLAN 1 to one of the firewalls.  You still have a single link on each firewall.  If the link going from vLAN 1 to the primary Sonicwall in the pair, the link will be down for the whole network.  Sonicwall HA is to protect against device failure not link failure.

Comment: Also if you place a switch in between the Firewalls and the routers you still have a single point of failure.

Comment: Creating a trunk also would not work as the WAN connections coming in have distinct IP settings that would need to be configured on the Sonicwall.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree.  You configure Physical Link monitoring and that will cause the backup FW to take over when the link goes down (see for example http://kb.guru-corner.com/question.php?ID=308 ). the WAN routers are (or could be) configured for HSRP.  The VLANs on either side of the FW are spanned across two switches, so they are not single points of failure.  The trunk connects the two switches (with two VLANs) together.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the vLAN, sorry the diagram didn't show two devices for vLAN 1 and I misread the description.  I also had to go read the specs for HSRP as that is a Cisco protocol.  You can configure a single interface on the Sonicwall to point to a single gateway device and HSRP handles the failure of one router and takes over the MAC and IP settings for routing.  With two switches and the setup you are describing, (now that we're on the same page :-) ) should allow for proper failover protection.

Comment: I would also suggest using the Logical Link monitor for protection of LAN-side failures as well.  That way if something downstream failed between Sonicwall 1 and the LAN, Sonicwall 2 would pickup the slack.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Ron.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  A +1 for your troubles ;)

Comment: Not a problem.  We're all here to learn new stuff. ;-)

Comment: The routers each have a unique IP, and then a shared IP that we use as our gateway. I don't control them, but I believe they are using HSRP. Any suggestions on how to physically connect the two switches that make up VLAN 1 into the Sonicwall? It only has 1 designated WAN port, and none of the other ports can be L2 bridged to it (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Never mind that last comment... I think I see what you mean, you're suggesting to physically connect switch 1 to Sonicwall 1 and switch 2 to Sonicwall 2. Then let the Sonicwall failover if it can't access the shared gateway. I'm going to give that a try right now.

Comment: @JakeBraun That's right.  I guess I could have made it clearer in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

you could use port redundancy on the Sonicwall if it is NSA2600 or above & Sonicos 6.2 and above.

https://documents.software.dell.com/sonicos/6.2/administration-guide/network/configuring-interfaces/network-interfaces/configuring-interfaces/configuring-link-aggregation-and-port-redundancy?ParentProduct=849

Comment: Rather than just posting a URL (as they can expire, move, be deleted/updated etc) can you give a one or two sentences on this feature and why it mightbe of us?